# Tags: [pin], [pins], [pinout]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I'm pretty sure that the tags [pin](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pin) and [pins](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pins) mean the same thing and should be merged. Are they synonyms of [pinout](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinout)? If not, they could use a tag wiki that explains the difference.

While we're on the subject of plurals, [fuse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuse) and [fuses](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuses) should be merged. Since it is now impossible (except for moderators) to create tag names that look like singular/plural pairs (it wasn't when the site started), and [that's the lot of them](http://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/72948/tags-with-similar-names), this issue won't come up again.

Comment: With respect to fuse/fuses, is there any difference between hardware fuses that blow on high current, and fuses that configure a microcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and merged [pin](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pin)->[pins](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pins) and [fuse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuse)->[fuses](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuses).

There's some room to be pedantic about the difference between [pins](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pins) and [pinout](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinout), but I'm not sure that it's necessarily worth enforcing or cleaning. Right now, vote for *this* post if you agree with merging [pinout](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinout) -> [pins](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pins). Otherwise, suggest an alternate course of action in an answer below.

Comment: If you ask me, pinout should be nuked. It's a pointless tag that really doesn't provide any insight to the content of a question.

Comment: Maybe 'pinout' could be useful in the FPGA context (timing)? Not sure. But I don't think pinout and pins should be merged though.

Comment: Just now i tagged http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108356/powering-peripherals-from-a-microcontroller-atmega328p with pins, though it is not about pinout anyway.